# How to group by a specific given values by Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
a     b     c
1     2     5 
1     3     5
1     4     4
2     5     3
```

I know the value of every column could only range from 1 to 5 so I try this

`df.groupby([1,2,3,4,5]).count()`

I got this

```
      a     b     c
1     1     1     1 
2     1     1     1
3     1     1     1
4     1     1     1
5     1     1     1
```

Which is totally wrong, my expectation for this is to `count` group by `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

EXPECTATION:

```
          a     b     c
  1       3     0     0 
  2       1     1     0
  3       0     1     1
  4       0     1     1
  5       0     1     2
[null]    0     0     0
```

Comment: [`df.apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0)`](https://uscript.co/public/Google_108617488638529745626/python/d18ceea3.py)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will do `stack` + `unstack`

```
s = df.stack().groupby(level=1).value_counts().unstack(0,fill_value=0)
Out[183]: 
   a  b  c
1  3  0  0
2  1  1  0
3  0  1  1
4  0  1  1
5  0  1  2
```